# How do I power up my studio?

Tags: pushmo

I was trying to load Pushmo puzzles from QR codes (specifically, the Megaman one [here](http://www.pocketgamer.co.uk/r/3DS/Pullblox/feature.asp?c=36101), and I got this message: "This Pushmo is too advanced for you! You need to power up your studio first."

What does that mean? What do I need to do to power up my studio, and what does powering it up mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep progressing in the main game.

Every once in a while, after solving a puzzle, the old guy who usually congratulates will say you've unlocked a new feature in the studio, for example. a large canvas. Here's what's unlocked and when, according to [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/644719-pushmo/cheats):

> **Unlockable** - **How to Unlock**
>   32 by 32 grid - Complete the first level of Murals 2.
>   Gadgets - Complete Advanced Lesson 1.

There might be other unlockable stuff, I don't recall what else I might've unlocked and when

Comment: The ladders and arrows are unlocked at different times, I think.